# ¿Comó mostrar un numero flotante en un EditText de tipo numberDecimal?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, formato

Hola a todos lo que pasa es que tengo un `EditText` con las siguientes propiedades

```
   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/txttiempo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Tiempo"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
```

Y lo que quiero hacer es establecer un valor mediante la propiedad `setText` pero me marca un error y cierra la aplicación sé que es debido a que no acepta el dato que introduzco que es un número con punto decimal de la siguiente manera.

```
float to =11.1;
unidades.setText(to);
```

Es necesario que sea un numero con **decimal** debido a que son datos que son extraídos desde una base de datos y es necesario mostrarlos para poder realizar la actualización de registros.
Cabe mencionar que ya intente con la conversiones numéricas pero no me lo permite.
Les agradecería mucho la ayuda.

Comment: prueba `unidades.setText(Integer.toString( (int) to ) );`

Comment: Observa que se hace redondeo mediante cast

Comment: @quevedo De esa manera si acepta el número, pero solo me muestra 11 y necesito que muestre 11.1 y no puedo modificar esos valores redondeando debido a que los utilizare posteriormente y necesito de mucha exactitud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día el problema esta en que al enviar un texto a un EditText este debe ser un texto y tu estas enviando un float lo que debes hacer es un cast del float a String y enviarlo a tu EditText de la siguiente manera:

```
float to = 11.1f;
editText.setText(String.valueOf(to));
```

Espero te sea de utilidad saludos.

Comment: Gracias amigo funciono a la perfección, disculpa la pregunta pero soy nuevo en esto

Comment: De nada @Alfredo y no te preocupes para eso estamos saludos.